# Rails CanCanCan & Defining Abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, cancan, scopes, cancancan

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I am using CanCanCan for permissions and Role_Model for roles management.

In my ability.rb, I have defined student abilities as:

```
 elsif user.try(:profile).present? && user.profile.has_role?(:student)

      student_abilities
```

and then:

```
def student_abilities
can :read, Project.visible.current.available
```

In my project.rb I have defined scopes as:

```
    scope :visible, lambda { joins(:sweep => :disclosure).where('disclosures.allusers' => 'true')
        .joins(:sweep => :finalise).where('finalises.draft' => 'false') }
  scope :current, lambda { where('project.start_date >= ?', Date.today)}
  scope :available, lambda { where('closed =', 'false')}
```

When I try to start the server and generate a view, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /project_invitations
undefined method `available' for #<Project::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fdde41f2ee8>
```

When I try removing available from the end of the ability, so that its just:

```
can :read, Project.visible.current
```

I get this error:

```
 entry for table "project"
LINE 1: ..." = 'true' AND "finalises"."draft" = 'false' AND (project.st...
                                                             ^
```

I don't know why it won't let me read the end of the error message.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the table name. Is it really called "project", not "projects"?
2. The way you describe scopes is a bit weird. E.g. instead of `where('closed
   =', 'false')` I would describe it as `where(closed: false)`, minimizing the number of SQL-aware fragments

Comment: Hey, I tried to pluralise the name of the model (as it is showing in the db schema) and for a minute that worked, but now, in my CanCanCan ability.rb, I get an error which says: uninitialized constant Ability::Profiles. It stops throwing this error when I remove the 's' and go back to the singular.  I saw another post on SO that says its the name of the model that you're supposed to reference (which would be singular). any ideas?